# about a criterion for compacted and connected sets in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The next exercise had been difficult for me. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Be $K$ a subset sequentially compact of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. Proof that $K$ is not connected iff exist two nonempty subsets  $A$ and $B$ of $K$, disjoint, with $A \cup B = K$ and  $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $||u-v||> \varepsilon$ for all $u \in A$ and $v \in B$.

At the end also have to respond this question: is needed the assumption of sequential compactness for the existence of such an $\varepsilon$?

i attempted to prove it first supposing that if this set is not connected then there exists two open sets U and V that separate the set K and supposing that there is no such an $\varepsilon$ that arrives two sequences one in $U \cap K$ and the other in $V \cap K$ that converge to the same point. From there i know that this limit is in $K$ but i don't know where comes the contradiction i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that $A$ and $B$ are closed by the assumption that $K$ is not connected. But closed in compact set implies compact and two disjoint compact set in a metric space have always positive distance. We can use the following:

***Lemma:*** if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $d(A,B)>0$.

*Proof:* the function $f(x)=d(x,B)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is well defined and since A is compact $f$ has a minimum in $A$, which is strictly positive since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets.

*Remark 1:* the "if" proof is clearer. In fact you might consider $U = \{x \in K : d(x,A) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $V= U = \{x \in K: d(x,B) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ which are an open partition of $K$

*Remark 2:* in a metric space sequentially compact and compact are equivalent.

*Remark 3:* you need compactness because you might think of $A= \mathbb{R} \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $B = graph(exp) \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. $K = A \cap B$ have not that property.

Comment: Tyvm! just left a doubth behind. How can i see that A and B are closed by the assumption that K a compact not connected.  I mean im considering that $A= U \cap K$ and $B = V \cap K$ where U and V separate K (are open) also its true that any two disjoint sets such that $A \cup B = K$ where K is compact are closed?

Comment: @Nicolas in a topological space X, if $C \subset X$ is not connected then there exists two disjoint closed set of $C$, say $A$ and $B$, such that $C=A \cup B$. If you want, this is by definition of connectedness.

Comment: Now i see it better just that i manage this definition of conectedness: A set A in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is said to be conected iff there exists two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that 1) $U \cap A  \neq \varnothing$ and $V \cap A  \neq \varnothing$ 2) $( U \cap A)  \cap ( V \cap A) = \varnothing$  and 3) $( U \cap A)  \cup ( V \cap A) = A$ can u help me to see the equivalence with your definition

Comment: @Nicolas what you wrote is correct all but the fact that it is the definition of NOT connected.

Comment: Sorry,  i miss the not while writing but yes, i understand. Just  im trying to figure out how to write the exercise because the book don't use the definition by closed sets so how we can see the equivalence

Comment: @Nicolas notice that in your definition above, $C=U^c$ and $D=V^c$ are closed and they have the same property of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: just figured out! was about to write it tyvm for all your help, have a nice day.